# Why does 'API' requests return 'None' in grequests while 'normal web scraping' gives a 200 response

Tags: python, api, python-requests, grequests

### EXAMPLE:

The below code is capable of getting multiple web results with grequests but why on earth does it fail with "*making simple api calls*"

### CODE:

```
import grequests

links = [
    'https://api.github.com/users?since=135',
    'http://www.google.com',
    'https://api.github.com/users?since=135',
    'http://www.google.com'
]

a = (grequests.get(i) for i in links)
p = grequests.map(a)
print(p)
```

Why the heck is the output not: (**Response [200], Response [200], Response [200], Response [200]**)

But: (**None, Response [200], None, Response [200]**)

...just skipping the **api calls** in purpose ):

Comment: why don’t you try just using simple requests and see if you can reach those github endpoints seeing as they both fail

Comment: because i want them all at once

Comment: you’re missing the point here, for simple debugging purposes to rule out that the endpoint itself is a problem, try reaching the endpoint by itself outside the scope of this function

Comment: also I can't reproduce this error, it works fine for me

Answer (score 2):

If the requests library (as used by grequests) returns `None` as the response (for whatever reason), grequests lets you handle that however you'd like, by calling an exception handler callback function that **you** create and then pass to `map`.

From `grequests.py` (in the `map` method):

```
    for request in requests:
        if request.response is not None:
            ret.append(request.response)
        elif exception_handler and hasattr(request, 'exception'):
            ret.append(exception_handler(request, request.exception))
        elif exception_handler and not hasattr(request, 'exception'):
            ret.append(exception_handler(request, None))
        else:
            ret.append(None)
```

What is happening here? Before this block executes, grequests will have raised all of the requests, and now we're looping through the results. For each request:

- If you get a `response`, return that.
- If an exception handler is registered and the `request` has an `exception` defined, call the handler and pass it the `request` and `exception`.
- If an exception handler is registered and the `request` **does not** have an `exception` defined, call the handler and pass it the `request`.
- If the `response` was `None`, but no handler is registered, return `None`

The last case results in data loss, but it's preventable by using a callback that properly handles the exception. What exactly `exception_handler` does is something you need to define, then include like this:

```
response = grequests.map(request_getters, exception_handler=my_handler)
```

what the handler does is up to you, but maybe this would be helpful:

```
MAX_PARALLEL_REQUESTS = 2

links = [
    'https://api.github.com/users?since=135',
    'http://www.google.com',
    'https://api.github.com/users?since=135',
    'http://www.google.com'
]

def my_handler(request, exception):
    links.append(request.url)
    print(f"exception thrown by grequests: \n{exception}")
    return request

while links:
    a = (grequests.get(links.pop(0)) for _ in range(MAX_PARALLEL_REQUESTS))
    p = grequests.map(a, exception_handler=my_handler)
    print(p)
```

This is pop a fixed number of URL's off the `links` list each iteration of the `while` loop. If any of those requests should fail, `my_handler` is called, which adds the failed URL back to the `links` list for reprocessing.

Answer (score -2):

finaly i've realised that all i needed was to hardcode it with loops instead of using grequests.

### Here

:

```
import requests, time

links = [
    'https://api.github.com/users?since=135',
    'http://www.google.com',
    'https://api.github.com/users?since=135',
    'http://www.google.com'
]

sd = []

for i in links:
    try:
        d = requests.get(i)
        time.sleep(1)
        sd.append(d)
    except:
        sd.append(False)

print(sd)

#note that time.sleep(*) is only optional.
```

...don't know why grequests behaves so.

Comment: I guess it works, but it's not a good solution as grequests is multithreaded, and this isn't